# Smallest $n$ such that $U(n)$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_5 \oplus \mathbb Z_5$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I solved the following exercise:

Find an integer $n$ such that $U(n)$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_5 \oplus \mathbb Z_5$.

Here $U(n)$ is the group of units modulo $n$.

To solve it I used that $U(st) = U(s) \oplus U(t)$ when $s,t$ are coprime and $U(p^n) = \mathbb Z_{p^n - p^{n-1}}$. I tried the first few primes until I found two with the property that $\mathbb Z_{p^n - p^{n-1}}$ is divisible by $5$.

My result:

$$ U(3025) = U(5^2 \cdot 11^2) = \mathbb Z_{20}\oplus \mathbb Z_{110}$$

It seemed clear to me that I had found the smallest number with this property since I chose the first primes I found. Then I looked at the solution which is

$$ n =275$$

> What other methods are there to solve this question so that I can find
>   the smallest such $n$?

Obviously, while possibly correct, my method does not find the smallest $n$.

Comment: Why use $11^2$ when $11$ works?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you. Indeed, why use $11^2$ -- I don't know!

Comment: Since $11$ is the smallest integer $a$ such that $5$ divides $\varphi(a)$, we should use $11$. This is explained in the answer by dREaM.

Answer (score 1):

By CRT we have $\mathbb Z_{p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_r^{\alpha_r}}\cong \mathbb Z_{p_1^{\alpha_1}}\times \mathbb Z_{p_2^{\alpha_2}}\times\dots\times \mathbb Z_{p_r^{\alpha_r}}$.

So $\mathbb Z_{p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_r^{\alpha_r}}^*\cong \mathbb Z_{p_1^{\alpha_1}}^*\times \mathbb Z_{p_2^{\alpha_2}}^*\times\dots\times \mathbb Z_{p_r^{\alpha_r}}^*$.

Now use the fact that $\mathbb Z_{p^{\alpha}}\cong \mathbb Z_{\varphi(p^\alpha)}$ for odd primes and $\mathbb Z_{2^\alpha}\cong \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_{2^{\alpha-2}}$.

From here we obtain $\mathbb Z_{p^{\alpha}}$ has at most one subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_5$, and it contains one if and only if $5|\varphi(p^\alpha)$.

So $n$ has at least two coprime prime power factors $p^a$ and $q^b$ so that $\varphi(p^a)$ and $\varphi(p^b)$ are multiples of $5$.

It is easy to see by inspection that the smallest two such values are $11$ and $25$. (this is because if $5|\varphi(p^a)$ then either $p\equiv 1\bmod 5$ or $p=5$ and $a>1$).

So the smallest value of $n$ so that $\mathbb Z_n^*$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_5$ is $25\cdot11$